# Inheriting from template instanciated with incomplete type

Tags: c++, templates, inheritance, incomplete-type

I have a struct template like the following:

```cpp
// S.h
#pragma once

#include <vector>

template <typename T>
struct S
{
    std::vector<T*> ts;

    virtual ~S() { for (auto* t : ts) t->foo(); } 
    void attach(T& t) { this->ts.push_back(&t); }
};
```

Then, I inherit a non-template struct, `ConcreteS`, from `S<A>`; `struct A`
being incomplete at this point, as I *only* forward declare it in
`ConcreteS.h`:

```cpp
// ConcreteS.h
#pragma once

#include "S.h"

struct A;
struct ConcreteS : public S<A>
// struct A incomplete here ^
{
    ConcreteS(); 
    ~ConcreteS() override; 
};
```

I include `A.h` in `ConcreteS.cpp` to make the definition of `struct A` visible
to the implementation of `ConcreteS`'s destructor:

```cpp
// ConcreteS.cpp
#include "ConcreteS.h"
#include "A.h"

#include <cstdio>

ConcreteS::ConcreteS() { std::puts("ConcreteS()"); }
ConcreteS::~ConcreteS() { std::puts("~ConcreteS()"); }
```

Finally, I instanciate `ConcreteS` in function `main`:

```cpp
// main.cpp
#include "ConcreteS.h"

int main()
{
    ConcreteS concreteS{};
}
```

The above code compiles (and runs) fine with:

- GCC 11.3.0;
- Clang 14.0.0.

The output is:

```
ConcreteS()
~ConcreteS()
```

But fails to compile on:

- Visual Studio 2019 (compiler: MSVC 19.29.30133.0);
- Visual Studio 2013 (compiler: MSVC 18.0.40629.0).

Here you are the error message from VS13 (the one from VS19 is similar):

```
Microsoft (R) Build Engine version 12.0.40629.0
[Microsoft .NET Framework, version 4.0.30319.42000]
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

  Checking Build System
  Building Custom Rule <proj_path>/CMakeLists.txt
cl : Command line warning D9002: ignoring unknown option '/permissive-' [<proj_path>\build_vs13\tmp.vcxproj]
  A.cpp
  ConcreteS.cpp
  main.cpp
<proj_path>\S.h(10): error C2027: use of undefined type 'A' [<proj_path>\build_vs13\tmp.vcxproj]
          <proj_path>\ConcreteS.h(5) : see declaration of 'A'
          <proj_path>\S.h(10) : while compiling class template member function 'S<A>::~S(void)'
          <proj_path>\ConcreteS.h(8) : see reference to class template instantiation 'S<A>' being compiled
<proj_path>\S.h(10): error C2227: left of '->foo' must point to class/struct/union/generic type [<proj_path>\build_vs13\tmp.vcxproj]
  Generating Code...
```

**Question:** Who is right? Visual Studio or GCC/Clang?

For reference, I also post the declaration and definition of `struct A` and my
`CMakeLists.txt`:

```cpp
// A.h
#pragma once

struct A
{
    void foo() const;
};
```

```cpp
// A.cpp
#include "A.h"
#include <cstdio>

void A::foo() const { std::puts("A::foo()"); }
```

```
# CMakeLists.txt
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.6)
project(tmp)

add_executable(tmp A.cpp A.h ConcreteS.cpp ConcreteS.h S.h main.cpp)

if (MSVC)
    target_compile_options(tmp PRIVATE /W4 /WX /permissive-)
else()
    target_compile_options(tmp PRIVATE -Wall -Wextra -pedantic -Werror)
endif()
```

Comment: I would expect MSVC to be right on this one. At the point where `~S()` is being defined, `T` is an incomplete type, which is perfectly fine for declaring a `vector` of `T*` pointers, and a parameter of `T&` reference, but is not fine for calling `t->foo();` where `t` is an `A*` pointer, since the compiler doesn't know what `A` actually looks like yet.  So, gcc/clang are likely performing an extra delayed lookup that MSVC is not.

Comment: There is no need to muck with a multifile project, cmake and all this. [Live demo](https://godbolt.org/z/sWb4MMh69).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `S<A>` as base class causes it to be implicitly instantiated.

Generally that wouldn't be a problem since your class doesn't require `A` to be complete when it is instantiated.

However, the definition of your destructor for `S<A>` requires `A` to be complete (because of the member access). That would normally also not be a problem, because generally definitions of member functions are not implicitly instantiated with implicit instantiation of the class template specialization, but only when they are used in a context requiring a definition to exist or in the case of the destructor when it is *potentially invoked*.

However, your destructor is `virtual`. For `virtual` member functions in particular it is unspecified whether they are instantiated with implicit instantiation of the containing class. ([[temp.inst]/11](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4861/temp.inst#11.sentence-3))

So, the implementation may or may not choose to instantiate `S<A>::~S<A>` in the translation unit for `main.cpp`. If it does, the program will fail to compile since the member access in the definition is ill-formed for an incomplete type.

In other words, it is unspecified whether or not the program is valid and all mentioned compilers behave conforming to the standard.

If you remove `virtual` (and `override`) on the destructor(s) the only instantiation of the `S<A>` destructor allowed will be in the `ConcreteS.cpp` translation unit where `A` is complete and instantiation valid. The program is then valid and it should compile under MSVC as well.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Please let me check I understand this correctly. Clang and GCC implicitly instanciate `~S<A>` in `~ConcreteS`, because the latter needs to call the former. MSVC implicitly instanciates `~S<A>` in `ConcreteS.h`, when I inherit `ConcreteS` from `S<A>`. This causes the definition of `~S<A>` to "leak" to all the files where I include `Concrete.h` thus forcing me to include `A.h` as well (even if I don't use `ConcreteS` at all). Is this correct?

Comment: @paolo Yes basically. I don't know whether MSVC will instantiate `~S<A>` in _every_ translation unit including `ConcreteS.h`, but it probably does. For `virtual` member functions this is completely up to the compiler.